# Error while tapping - homebrew: tapping microsoft/mssql-release

Tags: sql-server, odbc, homebrew

I am following these steps to install `msodbcsql@13.1.9.2` on Mac OS 10.14.6

Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos?view=sql-server-ver15#13.1

After running the following command:

`brew tap microsoft/mssql-release https://github.com/Microsoft/homebrew-mssql-release`

I get the following errors:

```
Error: Non-symlink alias: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/microsoft/homebrew-mssql-release/Aliases/mssql-tools@17.6
Error: Non-symlink alias: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/microsoft/homebrew-mssql-release/Aliases/msodbcsql@13.1
Error: Non-symlink alias: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/microsoft/homebrew-mssql-release/Aliases/mssql-tools@17.7
Error: Non-symlink alias: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/microsoft/homebrew-mssql-release/Aliases/mssql-tools@17.0
```

Could anyone help me out here? or is there another way to install `msodbcsql@13.1.9.2` on MacOs?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and couldn't fix the problem! Finally, decided to **clone** the repository and manually install the Ruby files exist in the **Formula** folder

```
brew install --build-from-source msodbcsql17.rb
```